# Get a jar file from a path, and change its classes names

Tags: java, file

So I need to make a java console app that gets a jar file path and prints all the classes names to the console.

Then I want it to change all of the classes names to 3 random letters from the abc "ABC" (for example) and then I need it to create a new jar file with the same code in the classes but with the new classes names.

Now my idea for storing the classes code
ArrayList> that way each index will represent a class and each index of the ArrayList would represent a line in that class

also maybe will not need a decompiler if you can get the bytecode and just transfer it to the new file were creating

Now I don't really have much experience working with files like that in Java and in C# I have worked with files some times but not in that level, but I would be happy to learn, I also understand that it may be problematic to just create a new jar with the code of the old one

I hope there is a short efficient way to do what I need here

Also, I don't need this to be a big project right now and that's why I do everything in one class

here is what I got right now

```
    private static ArrayList<String> usedNames;
    private static final String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static Random rnd;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        usedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        usedNames.add("");
        rnd = new Random();

        // reading
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a jar path: ");
        String inputPath = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a output path: ");
        String outputPath = reader.readLine();

        // getting all class names from jar
        List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputPath + ".jar"));
        for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                // This ZipEntry represents a class. Now, what class does it represent?
                String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.'); // including ".class"
                classNames.add(className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length()));
            }
        }

        // print all classes names
        for (String s : classNames)
            System.out.println(s);

        // getting the code of each class to some sort of data structure

        // changing classes names to random letters

        // creating a new jar file with the classes in location outputPath
    }

    private static String getRandomClassName() {
        String str = "";
        while (usedNames.contains(str)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                str += letters.charAt(rnd.nextInt(27));
        }
        usedNames.add(str);
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to implement an obscator. Why not use a tool like proguard?

Comment: I want to create an obfuscator because I want to learn how it works

Comment: Of course, an obfuscater not only changes the class names, it edits the bytecode to change every reference to the classes that have now changed in name. *"I want to learn how it works"* My advice would be, set this aside and learn how to do simpler things.

Comment: well if there is a different approach to start with coding obfuscators that you would like me to start before I go for what I explained above please share it, also I know about the class referances I have already thougth about it but I just wanted to worry about it later